# Why won't this table use the specified dimensions?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a very big table with fixed cell widths and the parent container overflowing. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d38ye4kL/) where I want the container to overflow. Why is it not working and how to do it properly?

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tracks-container {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.sequencer-cell {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="tracks-container">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>reese</th>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        ...62 other cells...
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>guitar</th>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        ...62 other cells...
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Overflow in your fiddle seems to work fine for me (Chrome 79 MacOS 10.15.2). How do you want it to interact and on what target browser?

Comment: th tag inside tbody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min-width` instead, I have no idea why this works as i haven't done much with tables. Waiting for an explanation.

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tracks-container {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.sequencer-cell {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="tracks-container">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>reese</th>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>guitar</th>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the root cause of this but you can add `display: inline-block` to your cell class so that the browser can't ignore its width. You then have to add `white-space: nowrap;` to your container to prevent default wrapping.

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tracks-container {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.sequencer-cell {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table class="tracks-container">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>reese</th>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>guitar</th>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="sequencer-cell">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: When you use tables you must never touch the display property, that's what makes a table a table

Comment: @ZohirSalak To my knowledge this still behaves appropriately as a table.